# WCF global exception handling

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, wcf

i have build a global exception handling for my wcf application. I have a class that implements 'IErrorHandler' and handles the exception. I can register the ErrorHandler with a 'IServiceBehavior' attribute. (So i don't need to touch every function)

I use the class 'FaultException' to wrap my exception object.

```
Dim sysEx As SystemException = 'Do Convert
Dim fex As New FaultException(Of SystemException)(sysEx, sysEx.Message)
Dim faultMessage As MessageFault = fex.CreateMessageFault
fault = System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage(version, faultMessage, fex.Action)
```

Now I can retrieve the error message at client side. But unfortunally I can't retrieve the original exception type or the original stacktrace.

Is there an easy option to solve the problem without adding 'FaultContract' to each function in my service?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve & Saravanan are both correct. Here is how to create a custom fault type & how to use it:

Custom fault contract:

```
[DataContract]
public class UncaughtErrorFault
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ExecptionType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }
}
```

IErrorHandler method override:

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error,
                         MessageVersion version,
                         ref Message fault)
{
    var fe = new FaultException<UncaughtErrorFault>(
        new UncaughtErrorFault
            {
                ExecptionType = error.GetType().Name,
                Message = error.Message,
                StackTrace = error.StackTrace
            },
        error.Message,
        FaultCode.CreateReceiverFaultCode(
            new FaultCode(error.GetType().Name)));

    var mf = fe.CreateMessageFault();

    fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, mf, fe.Action);
}
```

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself wrong. How can I "publish" the class "UncaughtErrorFault" to the client side? The type is not added to the automatic generated "service reference"(of course). So WCF converts the fault back into a normal System.Exception and not in a "UncaughtErrorFault" object. How can i fix this problem?

Comment: To publish your custom faults, look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733841.aspx). It shows how to mark the service OperationContract methods with the FaultContract attribute that specifies your custom type. Your will however, need to mark each opertation method of the service to have the service reference include the necessary deserialization code. That was what I was referring to in my comment to @SteveWilkes

Answer (score 1):

Using `FaultContracts` and throwing `FaultExceptions` with custom `Fault` types is [the recommended way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx) of handing exceptions in WCF. If you need to retrieve the stack trace on the client side, you can set [includeExceptionDetailInFaults](http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/12/includeexceptiondetailinfaults-in-wcf-service-configuration.aspx) to true in your WCF behaviour config.

Comment: Unfortunately the service can throw normal .NET exceptions and has some "closed source" parts that also throw normal .NET exceptions. So I need a common and easy to handle way to convert .NET exceptions into SOAP faults. For this purpose I have written the code above.      Unfortunately I dont know how to create a custom fault that can contains more propertys without adding the FaultContract to every function.

Comment: You don't need to add a FaultContract attribute to the operation methods unless you want WCF to throw that custom fault. You can always catch the standard WCF FaultException because your custom fault is "embedded" in it. You could write an extension method for the FaultException type to extract any custom information you provide.

Answer (score 0):

In IErrorHandler.ProvideFault you are getting the exception in the first parameter. You can wrap that in your custom FaultMessage.

IErrorHandler.ProvideFault(Exception error,  MessageVersion ver,  ref Message fault)

Please refer to [IErrorHandler Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx#Y1479). This page provides an example on how to do this exception wrapping.